# django-forms-builder: Forms work from /admin but not directly

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

Below is my form url and it works fine when I got redirect to this url from `/admin`  and it was working fine before directly as well but now it throws the 404 when I try to access the url after submitting the form once. The error is shown in the image below

```
http://localhost:8000/forms/test
```

[image]

**project/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('forms/', include(forms_builder.forms.urls)),

]
```

Below image shows that it works fine if I access the form from here

[image]

Any idea what I may be doing wrong here?

Comment: Does the link take you to a different domain than `localhost:8000`?

Comment: It was happening before, I was redirected to `example.com` domain but I changed that to 'localhost:8000` from `/admin` and `sites` but now the link works fine when I try `POST` request but just the form link not working when I submit `GET` request directly

Comment: If you look at the [formbuilder code](https://github.com/stephenmcd/django-forms-builder/blob/fe518ad2bff9254f1fee4e5a650aaee46a9e9c32/forms_builder/forms/views.py#L30), you can see that GET requests call `get_context_data` but POST requests do not. You have to follow the code through and work out why the code is returning 404 (e.g. perhaps the form is not active for the `localhost:8000` site).